# using ansible pam_limits module to change max user processes, but failed

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

I deployed ansible 2.1.1.0 with python 2.7.12 on Redhat 6.5. And I tried below script to modify max user processes, it runs with no failed msg but did not have effects on max user processes.

I know I can try other ways by editing /etc/security/limit.d/90-nproc.conf using either copy module or shell module, but since ansible offers pam_limits module, i guess this may be more graceful.

```html
- name: set ulimit nproc use_max
      pam_limits: domain=* limit_item=nproc limit_type=- value=unlimited use_max=yes
```

Comment: So what was the status of the task? Once you wrote "failed" the other time "no failed msg". Was it `changed` or not? Does the config file `/etc/security/limits.conf` contain different values than expected?

Comment: running the script did not return any error message., but when i check  with "ulimit -u", it still shows 1024.

Comment: And do I need to repeat all the questions I asked?

Comment: string "- nproc unlimited" was appended to file /etc/security.limits.conf . but in Redhat 6.5, the actual config file for nproc is /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible [`pam_limits`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pam_limits_module.html#synopsis) module uses `/etc/security/limits.conf` by default.

You need to add a `dest` parameter to specify path to a different file.